# Join/Merge 2 data sets based on specific column conditions in PROC SQL/SAS

Tags: sql, join, merge, sas, proc-sql

I have the following data sets

table_A

| user_cd | item_nbr | product_cd | part_cd | line_grp | from_geo | to_geo | between_geo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | AL | AZ |  |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 |  | PR |  |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 |  | WA |  |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 |  | NV |  |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | NY | NJ |  |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 |  | PA |  |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | WY | AZ |  |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | TX | TX |  |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 |  | CA |  |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 |  |  | NJ |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 |  |  | CA |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 |  |  | ND |

table_B

| user_cd | item_nbr | product_cd | part_cd | line_grp | oprtr_cd | oprtr_typ | num_value | zone_a | zone_b | zone_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | A | $ | 140 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | B | % | 15 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | C | % | 15 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | A | $ | 200 | TRN | 1 | 2 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | B | % | 25 | TRN | 1 | 2 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | C | % | 25 | TRN | 1 | 2 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | A | $ | 175 | TRN | 2 | 5 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | B | % | 33 | TRN | 2 | 5 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 1 | 29 | C | % | 38 | TRN | 2 | 5 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | A | $ | 140 | PQR | 37 | 1 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | B | % | 15 | PQR | 37 | 1 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | C | % | 15 | PQR | 37 | 1 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | A | $ | 200 | PQR | 41 | 8 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | B | % | 25 | PQR | 41 | 8 |
| 01 | 255258 | 54147 | 2 | 30 | C | % | 25 | PQR | 41 | 8 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | A | $ | 100 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | B | % | 15 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | C | % | 27 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | A | $ | 100 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | B | % | 15 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 1 | 60 | C | % | 27 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 | A | $ | 100 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 | B | % | 15 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 | C | % | 27 | TRN | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 | A | $ | 100 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 | B | % | 15 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 03 | 999999 | 22222 | 2 | 99 | C | % | 27 | ABC | 1 | 2 |

I want the following output (or the closest equivalent)

[image]

How can I get this? I am open to SAS or PROC SQL

Here is a snippet what I am actually getting if I use any kind of join directly for table_A and table_B..

[image]

Comment: The first group in A has 4 observations. The first group in B as 9 observations.  Your resulting picture appears to have 12 observations in the first group.  Why?  Explain the logic for matching them in that way.

Comment: Yes, the first group has 4 observations and the second group has 9 observations, but those 9 observations have 3 subgroups in them...so I want to match in this way..
4 obs from table_A matches with the 1st subgroup (of 3) from table_B, then 4 obs from table_A matches with the 2nd subgroup (of 3) from table_B and so on..Basically from table_A grouping of (user_cd, item_nbr, product_cd, part_cd, line_grp, from_geo, to_geo) should match grouping of (user_cd, item_nbr, product_cd, part_cd, line_grp, zone_a, zone_b, zone_c) from table_B..because of the extra columns of table_B and the subgroups

Comment: ...because of the extra columns of table_B and the subgroups it creates, the results are similar to that of an inner join and I want a SAS Merge type solution. I know I can do this by adding counters, but the thing is the number of zones in zone_c are dynamic so don't know how to go about it.

Comment: When you same match 4 obs with 3 obs what do you mean?  Do you mean pair the  first with the first, second with the second and third with the third and nothing with the fourth?

Comment: I added a snippet of the output of the join on first 4 rows of table_A and join with first 9 rows of table_B..any kind of join gives me 4*9 = 36 rows..where as I want only 12 rows   
(4 to_geo rows * 3 of any of oprtr_cd/oprtr_typ/num_value/zone_a/zone_b/zone_c rows; as their grouping would be unique)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to merge based on the first 5 columns and then get all the possible combinations between the other columns (the non-merged ones).

I would use a CROSS JOIN in SQL. (https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/)

The query would look something like this:

```
-- Query to merge the tables based on the first five columns using CROSS JOIN
SELECT 
    table_A.user_cd,
    table_A.item_nbr,
    table_A.product_cd,
    table_A.part_cd,
    table_A.line_grp,
    table_A.from_geo,
    table_A.to_geo,
    table_A.between_geo,
    table_B.oprtr_cd,
    table_B.oprtr_typ,
    table_B.num_value,
    table_B.zone_a,
    table_B.zone_b,
    table_B.zone_c
FROM table_A
CROSS JOIN table_B
WHERE table_A.user_cd = table_B.user_cd
  AND table_A.item_nbr = table_B.item_nbr
  AND table_A.product_cd = table_B.product_cd
  AND table_A.part_cd = table_B.part_cd
  AND table_A.line_grp = table_B.line_grp;
```

Comment: The problem with Cross Join is that because of 4 rows of to_geo from table_A (in user_cd = 01 |  item_nbr = 255258 | product_cd = 54147 | part_cd = 1 | line_grp = 29 | from_geo = AL) the operator_cd values of A,B,C causing 3 rows from table_B gives a total of 12 rows of results instead of 4 rows...basically repeat of rows due to multiple to_geo rows..that's why I get way more rows than intended